# Embedding abelian categories into abelian sheaves

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, constructive-mathematics, abelian-categories, embeddings

The Yoneda functor from an abelian category into sheaves of abelian groups is shown to be exact in The Stacks Project, Lemma 19.9.2. I like this proof because it is constructive and it doesn't use injective/projective objects (as for instance the FM Embedding Theorem does). Is there anyone which has in mind a published references with an analogous proof?

Comment: Welcome on MO, Anna! I too like that proof very much. It's the workhorse of my favourite approach to diagram chasing in abelian categories: use the internal language of the resulting sheaf topos. (If desired, the definition of internal language can be unrolled to eliminate all mentions of sheaves and even sets, working just fine in restricted predicative foundations, yielding a convenient interface to [this little jewel](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/unpub/elem-chase.pdf) by George Bergman.

Comment: Unfortunately I also don't know a precise reference. The construction has certainly long been known in the topos community; it is an instance of "sheaves with respect to the [regular topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology#regular_topology)". Perhaps this helps in tracking down a reference.

Comment: Numbered references in the stacks project are not stable. Please use [tags](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags) instead.